# Combining 2 reports into one 1 in (testng) allure

Tags: java, testng, xunit, allure

My requirement is to combine 2 test results to publish an allure report. Basically, our framework needs run 2 exclusive sets of related tests bases on system status as 2 different test runs. These will run from 2 different JVMs. I need to combine the result of these 2 runs to show 1 report.

As allure provides an adapter for testng, I'm wondering if this is possible or where should I start.

Thanks in advance for all the guidance.

Comment: I would appreciate a comment for each downvote here. Is something not clear or does not make sense ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Allure has built-in aggregation functionality, just put two allure results bundles in one folder and use it as a source for your report. You will get report with two suites in it.

Comment: It is 1 suite. I select test from the suite based on environment condition. I should probably have explained it in further details in the question itself. Here is an example of test class :

Comment: here is the situation explained here :

Comment: I left comment there. Anyway Allure will show any result that you have from several runs of single suite. You need just collect all required results in one place.

Answer (score 5):

you can also use: `allure serve /path/to/results1 /path/to/results2`

Comment: How would you configure the job settings. Say if we need to merge three jobs output into one!

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan I didn't try, but why no passing 3 paths to allure serve? would that work? also, I think you can copy all of the artifacts from the folders into a single folder

Comment: My scenario is I have to execute three jobs separately and once all are completed. I have to run a job which uses the already executed three jobs raw report folders and create a consolidated Allure report. How would we move the folders from different jobs and make it

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan I'm not sure I understand. did you try to use `cp` to copy the files to where you need them?

Comment: I got that, I tried moving all those folders to a common folder and generated it with bash script