# How can I merge 2 allure reports together?

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins, allure

I have a test suite of around 5000 test cases and not all test cases pass in 1 run always due to any environmental issue or any other problem, so we have to **execute the testNG-failed.xml most of the time again**. But it creates 2 allure reports and we have to share 2 or more reports to the stakeholders, which is unacceptable to the stakeholders.

Can we merge these 2 reports so that a final allure report will have all test cases which are marked as pass if the test case is passed in any of the reports and marked as failed if it is failed in both reports?

*Note: We are using jenkins allure plugin for reports generation.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine reports - see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079396/combining-2-reports-into-one-1-in-testng-allure).
Also Allure 2 is clever enough to understand that you have several retries of the same test. This info is provided under retries tab.